# Feature alignment ORB process fail

Tags: python, c++, image-processing, orb

I am trying to align several images taken by UAV, combining thermal and RGB cameras. After doing ORB alignment and calculate the homography matrix, I call *warpPerspective* method and the result is always a blurred image. I have tried hundreds of pictures and the result is almost the same.

I have tried to raise MAX_FEATURES to 1000, 10000, 10000 and the result is always the same.

Any ideas why *warpPerspective* produces this kind of results? Perhaps is the homography matrix  mistaken?

Thank you in advance

[Thermal image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKNkT.jpg)

[WarpPerspective result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4o8xF.jpg)

[Another WarpPerspective result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eN9Ni.jpg)

```py
from __future__ import print_function

import cv2

import numpy as np

MAX_FEATURES = 500

GOOD_MATCH_PERCENT = 0.15

def alignImages(im1, im2):

  # Convert images to grayscale

  im1Gray = cv2.cvtColor(im1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

  im2Gray = cv2.cvtColor(im2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

  # Detect ORB features and compute descriptors.

  orb = cv2.ORB_create(MAX_FEATURES)

  keypoints1, descriptors1 = orb.detectAndCompute(im1Gray, None)

  keypoints2, descriptors2 = orb.detectAndCompute(im2Gray, None)

  # Match features.

  matcher = cv2.DescriptorMatcher_create(cv2.DESCRIPTOR_MATCHER_BRUTEFORCE_HAMMING)

  matches = matcher.match(descriptors1, descriptors2, None)

  # Sort matches by score

  matches.sort(key=lambda x: x.distance, reverse=False)

  # Remove not so good matches

  numGoodMatches = int(len(matches) * GOOD_MATCH_PERCENT)

  matches = matches[:numGoodMatches]

  # Draw top matches

  imMatches = cv2.drawMatches(im1, keypoints1, im2, keypoints2, matches, None)

  cv2.imwrite("matches.jpg", imMatches)



  # Extract location of good matches

  points1 = np.zeros((len(matches), 2), dtype=np.float32)

  points2 = np.zeros((len(matches), 2), dtype=np.float32)



  for i, match in enumerate(matches):

    points1[i, :] = keypoints1[match.queryIdx].pt

    points2[i, :] = keypoints2[match.trainIdx].pt

  # Find homography

  h, mask = cv2.findHomography(points1, points2, cv2.RANSAC)



  # Use homography

  height, width, channels = im2.shape

  im1Reg = cv2.warpPerspective(im1, h, (width, height))

  return im1Reg, h

if __name__ == '__main__':

  # Read reference image

  refFilename = "form.jpg"

  print("Reading reference image : ", refFilename)

  imReference = cv2.imread(refFilename, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

  # Read image to be aligned

  imFilename = "scanned-form.jpg"

  print("Reading image to align : ", imFilename); 

  im = cv2.imread(imFilename, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

  print("Aligning images ...")

  # Registered image will be resotred in imReg.

  # The estimated homography will be stored in h.

  imReg, h = alignImages(im, imReference)

  # Write aligned image to disk.

  outFilename = "aligned.jpg"

  print("Saving aligned image : ", outFilename);

  cv2.imwrite(outFilename, imReg)

  # Print estimated homography

  print("Estimated homography : \n",  h)
```

Comment: Your question seems to be missing the most important bit; *your current code* in [mcve] form. Why?

Comment: Ok. I did not post any code because I follow exactly the code published in OpenCV tutorial https://www.learnopencv.com/image-alignment-feature-based-using-opencv-c-python/

Comment: A Stackoverflow question should be "self contained" and not rely on external links. It needs to be useful for people for years to come and external links rot.

Comment: Added the code I have been using